# Blank page with vuejs 3 after vue serve

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Hi I do not know what happens really, because I have tried with two different libraries and they did not work.

I have installed VueJS 3, I did it with Vue Client.

It installed correctly and it worked, then I tried to create a view or component where I can see a video so I do these steps:

1. Step one:

   `npm i v-video-embed`  It worked correctly
2. Step two:
   I open main.js and I make these changes:

   ```
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import Embed from 'v-video-embed'

    const app = createApp(App).mount('#app')
    app.use(Embed)
   ```

How you can see I just add import Embed from 'v-video-embed', then I add const app and then I add app.use(Embed)

3. Step three:

   I create the view or component like this:

   ```
   <template>
    <video-embed src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4ObxcdXoFE"></video-embed>
    <video-embed src="https://vimeo.com/362754811"></video-embed>
    <video-embed src="https://dai.ly/x7n7y06"></video-embed>

   </template>

   <script>


   </script>
   ```

I save and then I run vue serve, it displays me localhost:8080 I put this on browser and the issue it is that it does not display anything just a blank page... and it does not display any console error.. so I wonder what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `use` method is used with root instance created by `createApp(App)` not the root component which is created by `app.mount('#app')`, so you should use `use` before `mount`:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
 import App from './App.vue'
 import Embed from 'v-video-embed'

 const app = createApp(App)
 app.use(Embed)

 app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, but it displays now this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_c') at Proxy.eval (video-embed.min.js?c3a4:1:1)

Comment: @thecode, v-video-embed only supports vuejs version 2 . You'll have to find another similar library or build one yourself if you want something like it in vue js 3.